# Confusion matrix raws are mismatched

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I've created a confusion matrix that works all right but its raws don't seem to be connected with the labels as should be.

I have some list of strings which is splitted into train and test sections:

```
 train + test:
 positive: 16 + 4 = 20
 negprivate:  53 + 14 = 67
 negstratified: 893 + 224 = 1117
```

The Confusion matrix is built on the test data:

```
 [[  0  14   0]
 [  3 220   1]
 [  0   4   0]]
```

Here is the code:

```
my_tags = ['negprivate', 'negstratified', 'positive']

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, title='Confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    logging.info('plot_confusion_matrix')
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(my_tags))
    target_names = my_tags
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, target_names, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, target_names)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label') 
    plt.show()

def evaluate_prediction(target, predictions, taglist, title="Confusion matrix"):
    logging.info('Evaluate prediction')
    print('accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(target, predictions))
    cm = confusion_matrix(target, predictions)
    print('confusion matrix\n %s' % cm)
    print('(row=expected, col=predicted)')
    print 'rows: \n %s \n %s \n %s ' % (taglist[0], taglist[1], taglist[2])

    cm_normalized = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    plot_confusion_matrix(cm_normalized, title + ' Normalized')
```

...

```
test_targets, test_regressors = zip(
    *[(doc.tags[0], doc2vec_model.infer_vector(doc.words, steps=20)) for doc in alltest]) 
logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, C=1e5)
logreg = logreg.fit(train_regressors, train_targets)
evaluate_prediction(test_targets, logreg.predict(test_regressors), my_tags, title=str(doc2vec_model))
```

But the point is that I actually have to look at the numbers in the resulting matrix and to change the order of my_tags so that they could be in accordance with each other. And as far as I understand this should be made in some automatic way. 
In which, I wonder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always best to have integer class labels, everything seems to run a bit smoother. You can get these using `LabelEncoder`, i.e.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
my_tags = ['negprivate', 'negstratified', 'positive']
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
new_tags = le.fit_transform(my_tags)
```

So now you will have `[0 1 2]` as your new tags. When you do your plotting, you want your labels to be intuitive, so you can use `inverse_transform` to get your labels, i.e.

```
le.inverse_transform(0)
```

Outputs:

```
'negprivate'
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't heard of LabelEncoder, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just sort-order of your labels, i.e. the output of `np.unique(target)`.

Comment: I suppose it happens in the linetest_targets, test_regressors = zip( *[(doc.tags[0], doc2vec_model.infer_vector(doc.words, steps=20)) for doc in alltest]) l

Comment: I mean if the first sentence has the label 'negstratified' than this label is the first raw in the matrix and so on. I can't catch how to manipulate the order with the code.